# how to set property value of a Control in ASP.net using Web.config in the web form

Tags: asp.net, html

How i can set the value of a property in ASP.net control? Assume my control is:

```
<asp:Label runat="Server" ID="Label1" Text="Value"></asp:Label>
```

I want to get `Value` from the web.config:

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManeger.AppSetting["ValueKey"]
```

What i must to do?

Please Excuse me for poor and bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%$ AppSettings:SettingKey%>'></asp:Label>
```

Where SettingKey is the Key name of your appsetting.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

C#:
    Label1.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValueKey"].ToString()

VB:
    Label1.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ValueKey").ToString()

Comment: I don't want to set in the code behind! I want to do this in web form

Comment: @Seyed Morteza Mousavi Try this :- <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BasePath"].ToString()%>'></asp:Label>

Answer (score 0):

Add Code to Page load like this :-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

Label1.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValueKey"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: I want to do this in the web form!